# PHP MySQL check user online last 30min and then select their thumbnail photo from another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, inner-join

I have two tables 'profiles' and 'photos'. I have a code that automatically updates DATETIME into 'Profiles > 'online' as a user navigates around the website. Then when the user goes to see everyone who is online I query the database, here is what I'm trying to achieve:

*QUERY1 - Select all users from Profiles where 'online' is less than 30minutes old.
*QUERY2 Select all users 'thumb' where 'user_id' matches QUERY1 and where 'profile'=1

The result I want is to return all users who have been active for the last 30 minutes and return the url to their thumbnail photo that is in a second table.

Profiles:

```
| user_id |  online  | user_ip |
+---------+----------+---------+
|   INT   | DATETIME | INT(10) |
+---------+----------+---------+
```

Photos:

```
|   id    | user_id |     image    |    thumb     |      profile    |
+---------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
|   INT   |   INT   | VARCHAR(200) | VARCHAR(200) |  ENUM('0', '1') |
+---------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

CURRENT CODE:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$time = strtotime($date);
$time = $time - (30 * 00);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);

if ($SQL = $DBcon->query("
SELECT  A.user_id as a_user_id, B.thumb as b_thumb
FROM profiles A
INNER JOIN photos B ON B.user_id = A.user_id AND B.profile='1'
WHERE A.online >= '$date'")) {

while ($online = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL)) {
        echo "<a href='profile.php?profile=" . $online['a_user_id'] . "' target='_blank'><img src='" . $online['b_thumb'] . "'></a>";
}
$SQL->free();
```

}

I have been trying now for two days and have hit a brick wall, any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: `$online['A.user_id']` should be `$online['user_id']`.

Comment: Thanks I've updated my code and tested it with your suggestion. It returns all the users who have been online for the last 30 minutes but does not return the thumbnail links and gives out following error:
"Notice: Undefined index: B.thumb in C:\xampp\htdocs\..... on line 47"

Comment: Ofcourse it should also be `$online['thumb']` - without table prefix. Two days - and you didn't read the error message? Next time just do `var_dump($online)` to see what your data looks like.

Comment: Ah, fantastic it's working. Thank you so much for your help Paul :)

Comment: Remember - the column names in the result do not include table prefixes. If you want to distinguish between equal column names, you have to use aliases (e.g. `select A.user_id as a_user_id ...`). You should also not use `select *` if you don't need all the columns. All you need is `SELECT A.user_id, B.thumb FROM ...`

Comment: I've updated the query to "SELECT  A.user_id as a_user_id, B.thumb as b_thumb" and it's working a dream. I've changed the references to $online['a_user_id'] & $online['b_thumb'].
Again you've been a fantastic help